# Split responsibilities for HTML <table> and CSV?

Tags: php, dry

I am trying to figure our what the best approach to split the responsibilities of HTML  view and CSV for export (same view data). I don't want to repeat to write same block of code of CSV when it is almost doing the same thing.

Example code below, firstly it get the data from the database, then it process it into  multidimensional array.   You can see I used a lot of `foreach` to generate report. Do I have repeat this for CSV export? There must be a DRY solution.

Example code below, how would you split the responsibilities for CSV and HTML?

```
function report($campaign, $agent, $startDate, $endDate) {

    $sql = "SELECT  count(*) as total, group_name, field, field, field, FROM table some ... inner joins table .. WHERE ... group by agent";

    $q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {

        $report[ $row['group_name'] ][ $row['item'] ] ['total'] = 0;
        $report[ $row['group_name'] ][ $row['item'] ] ['total'] += $row['total'];
        $report[ $row['group_name'] ][ $row['item'] ] ['agent'][$row['agent']] = $row;

        if (!array_key_exists($row['agent'], $fieldsAgent)) {
            ..... 
        }
    }

    $html = "<table>";

    $html .= " <tr>";
    $html .= "   <td>Group</td>";
    $html .= "   <td>Item</td>";

    foreach($fieldsAgent as $agentCol => $agentTotal) {
        $html .= "<td>$agentCol</td>";
    }

    $html .= "  <td>Total</td>";
    $html .= "  </tr>";

    foreach ($report as $category => $items) {

        foreach($items as $itemName => $itemData) {

            $html .= "<tr>";
            $html .= " <td>" . $category . "</td>";
            $html .= " <td>" . $itemName . "</td>";

            foreach($fieldsAgent as $fieldAgentName => $totalAgentUser) {

                    $total = $itemData['agent'][ $fieldAgentName ][ 'total' ];
                    $html .= "<td>" . $total . "</td>";
            }

            $html .= " <td>" . $itemData['total'] . "</td>";
            $html .= "</tr>";
        } 
    }

    $html .= "</table>";

    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: The DRY solution is to separate your presentation from your data logic, and then have two separate presentation layers (one for html, the other for csv).... this is what MVC is all about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a function called something like `tr_or_csv()`

```
function tr_or_csv($data = array(), $mode = 'csv')
{
    $result = '';

    if(is_array($data) && $data)
    {
        $mode = (is_string($mode) ? (in_array(strtolower($mode, array('csv','tr'))) ? $mode : 'csv') : 'csv');

        if($mode === csv)
        {
            $handle = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
            fputcsv($handle, $data, ',');
            rewind($handle);
            while (!feof($handle))
            {
                $result.= fread($handle, 8192);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        else
        {
            $result = '<tr><td>';
            $result.= implode('</td><td>', $data);
            $result.= '</td></tr>';
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

function report($campaign, $agent, $startDate, $endDate, $mode)
{
    // MySQL stuff, etc...

    $html.= tr_or_csv(array('Group','Item','Total'), $mode);

    // More code
}

report('new_campaign', 'Bob', '2015-01-01', '2015-07-10', 'tr');
```

Comment: I think I understand the logic you did, very interesting. Can you think of alternative solution.. Rather than executing `tr_or_csv()` for each row in the loop.  How about one function to fetch the data and return it, one function to output the data in html, one function to output the data in csv.  For example: `$output[]['column_name']='colum_value'` then you can format as CSV via a csv function that accepts array or pass to html?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back If you understand my code then why are you unable to think of a solution? You basically have to split what I did into two functions.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back In addition to DRY, you should also consider the YAGNI principle.